# Run all "initialization" cells

Tags: google-colaboratory

Is there any way to hack Google Colab to run all initialization cells, marked perhaps using a special comment like `#--init--`?

I want a way to automatically restart runtime and run all initialization cells.

So when I have a mix of exploratory and "production-ready" code in my notebooks, I have a way to run all "production-ready" cells after restart.

Mathematica Notebooks supports this usecase by giving the user two options:

- Evaluate Notebook (run all cells)
- Evaluate initialization cells (only run specially marked cells).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since there does not seem to bet a built-in feature in [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com) to run only the initialization cells, similar to what [Mathematica Notebooks](https://www.wolfram.com/technologies/nb/) offers, you might consider using a script.

As you mention, mark initialization cells using a special comment like `#--init--`.
The script will identify and execute these marked cells.
The idea would be to use a cell to trigger this script whenever you want to run the initialization cells.

```bash
[Trigger Cell] --> [Scripting Cell] --> [Initialization Cells]
    run_initialization_cells()          Execute cells with #--init--
```

Create a JavaScript function to iterate through all cells, identify initialization cells based on the special comment, and execute them.:

```js
%%javascript
// Step 2: Javascript Function
function runInitializationCells() {
    // Get all cells
    var cells = Jupyter.notebook.get_cells();
    
    // Iterate through all cells
    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        var cell = cells[i];
        
        // Check if the cell is a code cell and contains the special comment
        if (cell.cell_type === 'code' && cell.get_text().includes('#--init--')) {
            // Execute the cell
            cell.execute();
        }
    }
}

// Step 3: Triggering the Javascript
runInitializationCells();
```

Run a cell with the Javascript function whenever you want to execute the initialization cells.

Comment: Hm, I get `"'Shell' object has no attribute 'get_cells'"` on `notebook = IPython.get_ipython().get_cells()` -- https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JfnTvibVPD4vyFBXUz9Rqj49eeSdpV3l#scrollTo=g_FzTM_4fha0

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov True. I have edited the answer to propose a javascript-based option.

Comment: hm....am I holding it wrong? I run this in my notebook, but initialization cells don't seem to run -- https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JfnTvibVPD4vyFBXUz9Rqj49eeSdpV3l#scrollTo=Oh4e6jFUdglL

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov It is not working for me either. Do you see an "`Unrecognized runtime javascript; defaulting to python`", as described in [this article](https://dev.to/obenjiro/silence-of-the-fans-part-1-javascript-quickstart-5f3m)?